# Как сделать список Li ссылкой?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать список Li ссылкой с помощью стилей CSS, чтобы клик был не по самой ссылке, а по блоку списка?

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Разобрался. Кому нужно также, то ставим в стили на menu - 

.hmenu li {cursor: pointer;}
.menu li > a {display: block;}

Comment: оформи пожалуйста тогда в виде ответа

Comment: @PauloBerezini Добавил. Если что не так, прошу модераторов не кидать камни. Я тут еще не освоил как работать ))

Comment: все нормально, если будут вопросы пишите мне)

Answer (score 1):

Сделал сам буквально двумя стилями

```css
li {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
list-style-type: none; 
}

.menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
```

Comment: У вас список li не стал кликабельным, вы добавили ему `cursor: pointer;`

Answer (score 1):

Решение в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736693/217579) заставляет курсор менять свой вид над элементом списка, но кликабельной остаётся только зона ссылки внутри элемента списка.

Это нагляднее можно увидеть, если убрать правило CSS, меняющее вид курсора, и увеличить внутренние отступы у элемента списка.

Правильным решением будет убрать внутренние отступы у элемента `li`, добавить их элементу `а`, увеличить ширину элемента `li` на величину убранных внутренних отступов слева и справа:

```css
li {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 210px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}

.menu li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно здесь CSS использовать.

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <a href="#">главная ссылка</a>

    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Нет. Не так. Правильный код методом тыка )) Сделал и написал ниже

Answer (score 0):

Я бы задал li ширину - заполнение по содержимому и, на всякий случай, overflow:hidden - если li будет с округлением углов. А самой ссылке < a > display:inline-block и padding'ами задавал нужную ширину.

```
li{
  border:1px solid red;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:fit-content;    /*---*/
  border-radius:10px;  
  overflow:hidden;    /*---*/

a{
 display:inline-block;  /*---*/
 padding:15px 80px;     /*---*/
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]